# iOS to Node.js Backend SSL handshake failing

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, ssl, tls1.2

I have created a REST API with node.js and express. I am now trying to connect to the backend with a secure connection using Alamofire 3/https/SSL/TLS. I have a CA signed certificate, with a 2048 bit key installed on the server with the 'https' npm module. The error the server returns in xcode is below:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRFHN.png)

When I evaluate my SSLLabs it says certificate signed and TLS 1.2 / 1.1 all available etc as seen below. However interestingly under where it simulates requests the request record for iOS 9 (ATS) - Fails with 'Sever closed connection' as seen in the image below.

TLS connection completed successfully[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeCoC.png)

iOS 9 simulated request fails [3]

When I use the command:

nscurl --ats-diagnostics --verbose

Everything passes except the Default ATS Secure Connection and all three TLS exceptions as seen below:

ATS Default Secure Connection Failing[4]

3 TLS exceptions failing[5]

I am not sure what else to try as far as I understand I meet the requirements for ATS :

- TLS v1.2
- Forward Secrey (I am not sure how to test this)
- At least a 2048 bit key
  -

When I turn on CFNetworking logging in the logfile it points to Error code -1200 in CFNetwork/CFNetworkErrors.h which has the error reason 'The secure connection failed for an unknown reason.'

I am at a lost as to what to try next, thanks. Sorry it will only let me post 2 links so I had to remove some images.

Comment: On SSLShopper everything returns green, including the CA chain

Answer (score 0):

Answer - I had an old version of Node.JS installed on ther server 0.12. updated to v6 and now handshake words great